# isset not working on form submission (was actually db issue)

Tags: php, mysql

This was actually an issue with my database, not with my form or my isset.
If anyone would like to know how I fixed this in the end, Ill outline it here.

I did as in.k suggested and used the same query as I did in the form, then added in a few lines to generate some error codes, like so :

```
  // query execution
    $wr_pro = "INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, cat_id) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$price', '$categories')";
  $result = $db->query($wr_pro);
  print "$db->error()";
  if ($db->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed: ");
  }
  if ($result === TRUE) {
  echo "Product added successfully!";
}
  else {
  echo "Problem loading to database...";
  }
```

When I then loaded the page, I got a database error telling me that I needed to set default values for all the empty fields (it was an empty tag field that was causing the issue).

So yeah, I didn't set up my database correctly basically.
But I know in future now that error codes are awesome.

-------------- ORIGINAL QUESTION -----------------
I'm very new to this, so I'm sorry in advance if I've missed something very obvious, or my code is a bit messy.

I'm trying to make a page that writes a new product entry into an existing mysql database table.

From other questions asked, I've tried:

1. adding !empty with my isset
2. making sure that form method = "post"
3. making sure that stuff is actually getting saved to post (before isset)
4. tried printing the post after the isset and it didnt show up
5. making sure that the submit button name is the same as in the isset function
6. making sure the button name isn't submit
7. moving the isset to before the form (I'm not actually sure why I was supposed to do this so if anyone could explain, I'd be really thankful)

The errors for when it can't write to the database isn't showing, and it isn't writing to the database either, so I presume its the isset that isn't working? but I could easily be wrong.

I'm pretty sure the connection to database is working because the form has a category section it selects from the database, and that shows on the page fine.

I don't know if it's relevant but I'm running this on WAMP locally.

Anyone who could point me in the right direction, I'd be very grateful.

---- my code

```
    <?php
include("includes/connection.php");
include("includes/head.html");
include("includes/header.php");
?>
<div class="pagecontent">
  <h1> Create New Product:</h1>
  <!-- form submission action-->
  <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submitwrpro'])) {
  // escape user inputs
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['name']);
  $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['description']);
  $price = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['price']);
  $categories = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['category_id']);

  // query execution
  $wr_pro = "INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, cat_id) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$price', '$categories')";

  if(mysqli_query($db, $wr_pro)){
      echo "Product added successfully!";
                            }
      else{
      echo "Error writing to database $wr_pro. " . mysqli_error($db);
          }
  }
  ?>
  <!-- form entry -->
<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='name'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Price</td>
            <td><input type='text' name='price'></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td><textarea name='description'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Category</td>
            <td>
<!-- read product categories from the db -->
              <?php
              $req_cat = "SELECT cat_id, name FROM categories";
              $result = $db->query($req_cat);

              echo "<select class='form-control' name='category_id'>";
              echo "<option>Select category...</option>";
              if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                      extract($row);
                      echo "<option value=\"" . $row['cat_id'] . "\">" . $row["name"] . "</option>";
                                                        }
                                          }
                  else {
                      echo "no results";
                        }
              echo "</select>";
              ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
                <button name="submitwrpro" type="submit">Create</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</div>
<?php
include("includes/footer.php");
?>
```

Comment: Sorry, I said I tried printing the post after the isset, I mean in the isset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that you are connecting to db correctly. I don't see the connection file but the result that you are getting in the form in select has different way of connecting to db. I went through the form and did not find any errors. Try something like this

```
$connection = "INSERT INTO products (name, description, price, cat_id) VALUES ('$name', '$description', '$price', '$categories')";
$result = $db->query($connection);
echo "Product added successfully!";
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you so much for answering.
Ok, so I replaced my area under query execution with what you suggested, and you are right, it is now coming up with the Product added message, but it still isn't adding anything to the db.
the reason I tried using the other way was so I could see and error message if it couldnt write to the db for some reason, but this way seems  much more clear.

Comment: I found a different way to report the error for it not loading to the DB while keeping the same code I used in the form, and as you said it's definitely an issue with the database.
Now that I know where the issue is I should be able to get along ok - I was looking in the wrong place before >.<
Thank you so much, again!